# Call Prolog-File in C#

Tags: c#, json, prolog, jsonschema

I'd like to use the following Prolog program in my C# solution.
I've placed the 4 .pl files, which are located in the folder lib-pl, as a resource in my C# solution.

Now I'd like to run the following two commands, to get the JSON output:

use_module(library(http/json)).

xsd2json('/path/to/your.xsd',JSON),
  json_write(user_output,JSON).

How can I do this by using the following dll: http://www.swi-prolog.org/contrib/CSharp.html

I'd like to get the json schema from an xsd file by calling the prolog program, which will be called by my C# application.

Thanks!

Comment: Surprisingly, the link to [this library's documentation](http://www.lesta.de/prolog/swiplcs/Generated/Index.aspx) seems to be broken.

Comment: @AndersonGreen you can download the library. There's the documentation included.